# ¿Como mostrar el valor de una variable en pantalla HTML?

Tags: php

Soy nuevo en php y tengo que hacer un ejercicio. Según salga el nº de un dado pues tienes un premio u otro llamemoslo así, a mi se me ha ocurrido hacerlo así:

```
<?php
        $costoPartida = 10;
        $creditos = 100;

        function partida() {
            $creditos -= 10;
            $resultado = math . random_int(0, 9);
            switch ($resultado) {
                case 2:
                    $creditos += 25;
                    $comentario = "has ganado 25 creditos";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $creditos += 100;
                    $comentario = "has ganado 100 creditos";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    $creditos += 5;
                    $comentario = "has ganado 5 creditos";
                    break;
                default:
                    $comentario = "intentalo de nuevo";
                    break;
            }
            return $comentario;
        }
        ?>
```

El problema es llegado al htlm que me muestre los creditos que me quedan no se como poner una etiqueta y importar el valor de la variable.
    Por ahora esto llevo del htlm

```
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>5 magico </title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        </head>
        <body>
        <from name="InferfazPartida" method="post" action="Partida.php">
            <p>Patida del 5 magico</p>
            <br/>

        </from>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: A ver si te entiendo. Vos queres recibir en la misma pantalla en la que tenes el formulario (que por cierto, tenes mal la etiqueta, es FORM, no FROM), los valores que devuelve tu codigo PHP? Para esto si no me equivoco vas a tener que usar Ajax. De otra manera, el formulario deberia llevarte a una pagina (aca te falta el SUBMIT del formulario, sino no vas a ningun lado) donde se impriman los valores como te indicaron en la respuesta.

Comment: y como hago todo eso?a ver yo tengo la variable creditos que segun se juegue va variando su valor y quiero que dicho valor se muestre en la pantalla

Comment: O muestras en la misma página todos los valores que va tomando $creditos, o recargas la página para ir mostrando el valor actual, o vas recargando el valor actual mediante Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Una opción podría dentro del archivo php que entiendo tenes ese html puede ser:

```
<?php echo $comentario; ?>
```

Y otro opciones la cual prefiero porque soporta diferentes estructuras de datos es:

```
<?php print_r ($comentario); ?>
```

Comment: Antes no habia salido completo la parte de php. pero eso es php mi pregunta es como hago para que la variable creditos en este caso salga en el htlm

Comment: Bien talves no entendi del todo la idea. Vos queres mostrar en ese html el comentario antes de o después de acceder? Interprete que previo a acceder a ese formulario ejecutabas ese codigo php.

Comment: No yo quiero mostrar en htlm los creditos que tengo, cada vez que yo tengo ya que cada vez que juegue bajan en 10 y aumentan segun el nº que salga

Comment: Y queres que sea en php si o si?

Comment: Tiene que ser porque en trabajo tiene que ser en php jajaj si no lo hago en java y no tengo que preguntar seguramente jajaj Pero la asignatura en php y el tio dice que para el examen entra hasta funciones y no explica aprendemos por ciencia infusa

Answer (score 0):

Deberías de poner en el mismo archivo el HTLM y el PHP todo con extensión PHP, esto no es java que vas teniendo muchos archivo aquí las 2 cosas van juntas quizás por eso no te coge el valor de la variable. Prueba esto en el HTLM fuera de form

```
<p>Tienes <?php echo $creditos; ?>  creditos</p>
```

y dentro pon `<input type="hidden" name="creditos" value="<?php echo $creditos; ?>" />`
no soy un experto pero lo he probado y me funciona